# JDBC driver for MySQL - Query Wrapping?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, word-wrap

a simple question really, for which I cant seem to find an answer and am not going to reconfigure DB to log queries....

The question is: Does the driver automatically wraps all SQL queries/updates into

`START TRANSACTION; MyQuery; COMMIT;` ?

Or is there a way to configure it to do the above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [Connection.setAutoCommit(boolean autoCommit)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setAutoCommit%28boolean%29)
Here's its description from JDK document.

```
   Sets this connection's auto-commit mode to the given state. If a connection is in 
auto-commit mode, then all its SQL statements will be executed and committed as individual 
transactions.Otherwise, its SQL statements are grouped into transactions that are terminated 
by a call to either the method commit or the method rollback. By default, new connections are
 in auto-commit mode.
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for - didnt see it in the API first time around :(

Answer (score 1):

By default, JBDC autocommit mode is true, and we can set it with connection object 
please see example

[JDBC Autocommit](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/jdbc/jdbcexamples/jdbc-autocommit.html)

hope that helps

Comment: yes, thanks, I already read the API as off the first answer and got it to work as I wanted.